# Move Desktop Items

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I need some help with my code.
I currently work in a Citrix environment and keep running into a wall on line 4.
I have tried it with and without creating a variable called desktopicons.

When I run the first 3 lines it seems as if all the code works well till the fourth line.

The main idea of the PS script is to create a new folder move all desktop icons to this newly created folder.

```
mkdir -Name "newfolder" -Path "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\" -Force

Get-Process "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\*" |   Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null } | stop-process

$desktopicons="$Env: C:\Users\%username%\Desktop"

Move-Item -Exclude "$desktopicons\newfolder" -Path "$desktopicons*" -Destination "$desktopicons\newfolder\" -Force
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mix things up with a batch file. Here is my approach:

```
#get desktop path for current user
$DesktopPath = $ENV:HOMEDRIVE+$ENV:HOMEPATH+"\Desktop"

#create "newfolder" on users desktop
New-Item -Path $DesktopPath -Name 'newfolder' -Type Directory    

#move all files from desktop into "newfolder" excluding "newfolder"
Move-Item -Path $DesktopPath"\*" -Destination $DesktopPath"\newfolder" -exclude 'newfolder' -WhatIf
```

I added the parameter `-WhatIf` to see what to line actually does (instead of just doing it). If the output you get is OK with you you just have to remove this parameter to perform the task.